# Convert HTML file contents to XHTML in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, beautifulsoup

I have an html file in my S3 bucket. I have loaded the content of the file and now I want to convert the contents to XHTML using Python. I read about the BeautifulSoup library in python.Believe that's used to parse or convert the file to xml. Can you please help me with my problem on how to convert my html content to XHTML using python? I am very new to Python and have tried below code:
Please help-

```
try:
    # to read the content from s3
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    data = s3.get_object(Bucket='myBucketName', Key='myObjectKey')
    html_content = data['Body'].read()
    print("Content of file is-"+html_content)

    # to use beautifulsoup
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html_content,'lxml')
    return soup
except Exception as e:
    LOGGER.error(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
try:
    # to read the content from s3
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    data = s3.get_object(Bucket='myBucketName', Key='myObjectKey')
    html_content = data['Body'].read()
    print("Content of file is-{}".format(html_content))

    # to use beautifulsoup
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html_content)
    return soup
except Exception as e:
    LOGGER.error(e)
```

you can pass to BeautifulSoup the HTML string and it will be completed to XHTML format there is a need only to add the XHTML DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my goal is to convert the html content to XHTML. not XML

Comment: So you just need to add the XHTML tag to the existing HTML you have?

Comment: yes exactly I want to convert the contents from html format to xhtml format and Clean Unnecessary Tags and Attributes

Comment: The BeautifulSoup is already doing it for you so you can init the object BeautifulSoup(html_content) and it will complete it to the XHTML format you just need to add the XHTML header tag

Comment: Okay.. Are you suggesting to add the header tag manually to the code?

Comment: Yes that will make the BeautifulSoup object to be as the doctype that you will add

Comment: you can check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910216/editing-doctype-tag-with-beautifulsoup) to see how to add the doctype

Answer (score 1):

```py
import aiofiles
import asyncio
async def html2xhtml(page):
    async with aiofiles.open(page, mode='r+') as f:
        await f.seek(0, 0)
        await f.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.rstrip('\r\n') + '\n' + await f.read())
    os.rename(page, page.split(".")[0] + ".xhtml")

asyncio.run(html2xhtml("./foo.html"))
```